# \animategraphics does not show the poster image in pdf viewers without javascript support

Tags: viewers, printing, animate

Below is a minimal example that compiles fine but that does not show any image on viewers without javascript like evince, okular, xpdf, etc. Any ideas what going wrong (does not work either with the article class)? The animations work great on adobe reader though. I'm using TeX Live 2013/Debian.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}

\title{title}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{animate}
\begin{center}
\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,width=0.6cm,poster=first]{4}{image-}{1}{4}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue was fixed in version `2014/03/06`. Please update the `animate` package.